# What does this prove? (2)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Since 30 characters is required, here's some fluff:

*Illuminate Your Mind* with our brand new product of ... just kidding we don't have a product lol...

[image]

> think about 3-SAT

Hint:

> think logically

Comment: rot13(Guvf ybbxf yvxr n jvevat nhgbzngba va gur fglyr bs Jverjbeyq, ohg gur whapgvbaf qba'g ybbx evtug gb zr.)

Comment: *Abcr... Ohg lbh'er ba gur evtug genpx. Creuncf ersre gb fvzvyne chmmyrf V'ir znqr va gur cnfg?*